# Bad Request, bad URI 400 Error

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm 'ajaxing' my rails web app something I haven't done before. My goal is to add a product to the database without refreshing the page

I have a User and Product Controller. A user in his personal page adds a product. But I'm getting an 400 Error.

```
Bad Request

bad URI `/users/function (options) { return Utils.build_path([], ["format"],[2,[2,[7,"/",false],[6,"products",false]],[1,[2,[8,".",false],[3,"format",false]],false]], arguments); }'.
```

and also

```
bad URI `/users/function%20(options)%20%7B%20%20return%20Utils.build_path([],%20[%22format%22],%20[2,[2,[7,%22/%22,false],[6,%22products%22,false]],[1,[2,[8,%22.%22,false],[3,%22format%22,false]],false]],%20arguments);%20%20%7D'.
```

Product Controller code:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

respond_to :html, :json

    def create
        @product = Product.new(product_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            if @product.save
                format.html do
                    redirect_to '/'
                end
                format.json { render json: @product.to_json }
            else
                # Add a handler for unsuccessful cases
            end
        end

    end
    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:title, :units)
    end
end
```

User Controller, the show method:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @product = Product.new
end
```

The jQuery function that has the ajax functionality:

```
    $('.edit-box > form input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
        closeEdit();
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: Routes.products_path,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST'
        })
     });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a browser where you can monitor network requests (e.g. Chrome or Safari with inspector, or Firefox with firebug)?  If so, what does the response say for this request?  It will give you more details about what is wrong with the request.

Comment: I'm using Chrome (I've updated the post with the new information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Routes.product_path` is a javascript function so you need to call it with brackets. Without calling it you are putting the function code as url of your ajax call, and that's why you get a **BAD URI** error.

Try with:

```
$('.edit-box > form input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
    closeEdit();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: Routes.products_path(),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST'
    })
 });
```

Anyway you should set some params to send, or your controller will create an empty product if it's allowed or will return a **500 Error** if you have some validation on your model.

To send params use the `data` option. (Documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)

```
$('.edit-box > form input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
   closeEdit();
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: Routes.products_path(),
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", ... }
  })
});
```

### UPDATE

To get the value you can use the `serializeArray()` jQuery method on your form, but you will get an array of object with `name` and `value` of your form inputs. If you want a plain object, you can easly add the `serializeObject()` method to jQuery. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery))

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

/* Now you can use the method to serialize your form to an object */
var dataToSend = $('.edit-box > form').serializeObject()
```

Comment: how do I reference the keys and value from HTML form?